# compare multi value with foreach

Tags: php, foreach, explode

regex

```
a=1
b=2
c=4
d=17
g=9
...
```

is function for check if charecter and number same ....

```
    funnction compare($val1,$val2)
    {

    $val1=explode("|",$val1)
    $val2=explode("|",$val2)

    foreach(?)
{
    ????
}
    }
```

how i can compare with foreach 
i want copare pair $val1[1] with $val2[1] and if all Right return true

this is example of call function

```
 compare ("G|d|a","7|11|12")
    compare 
    g with 7
    d with 11
....
```

Comment: what is this kind of comparision based on? I cant spot any logical  connection between numbers and letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

What do you mean in copare pair $val1[1] with $val2[1] and if all Right return true?
Why not to use $val1===$val2 ?

you can use

```
$result=true;
for($i=0; $i<count($val1);$i++){
    $result = $result && ($val1[$i]==$val2[$i]);
}
```

Comment: why first result is false?